# How to make dot.product of 2D and 3D matrices (taking it for each dimension separately)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, dot-product

I need to calculate dot product of two matrices. Probably tensordot would do the job, however I am struggling to figure out exact solution.

The simple option

```
res = np.dot(x, fullkernel[:, :-1].transpose())
```

works fine, where x is of shape (9999,), fullkernel of shape (980,10000), and res is of shape (1, 980).

Now I need to do similar thing with 2 dimensions. Thus my x now has shape (9999, 2),  fullkernel (2, 980, 10000).

Literally I want my result "res" to be of 2 dimensions, where each one is dot.product of one column of x and one dimension of fullkernel.

Comment: What exactly should be the shape of `res`, `(2, 980)` or `(2, 2, 980)`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. I have succeeded somewhat a bit, but still not there yet. For now I used solution "res = np.dot(x.T, fullkernel[:, :-1, :])", where x (9998,2) and fullkernel is (2,9999,980), which gives me res (2,2,980), which is not exactly what I want. Because (2,2.n) means that each column of x was multiplied by each dimension of fullkernel. I would like to get res of shape (2,1,980), so first column of x is multiplied by first dimension of fullkernel, and second - by second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
res = np.einsum('ki,ijk->ij', x, fullkernel[:, :, :-1])
print(res.shape)
# (2, 980)
```

If you want to have the additional singleton dimension in the middle just do:

```
res = np.expand_dims(res, 1)
```

An equivalent solution with `@` / `np.matmul` would be:

```
res = np.expand_dims(x.T, 1) @ np.moveaxis(fullkernel[:, :, :-1], 2, 1)
print(res.shape)
# (2, 1, 980)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!